Rotating Tank of Charged Liquid
Consider a long rectangular tank of dimensions a×b, where a≫b, that is rotating at a constant angular velocity and filled with an incompressible charged fluid. How would one find an equation describing the surface of the liquid when in a stable state, taking into account the effects of the electric and magnetic fields produced by the liquid and its motion?
This is just a question that I've been thinking about and I couldn't find anything already answering it online. I have tried to solve for it, but I am not sure how to account for the effects of the interfaces around the liquid and the effects of the non-inertial frame on the fields.
Any help in how to properly approach this would be greatly appreciated.
(Apologies for any flaws in this post; this is my first time using the site.)


This is too broad of a question. The rules of this website dictate that you must always present your work. There are exceptions, but this is not the one. Anyway, in the classical case, to get the free surface equation for a rotating cylinder, we simplify the Navier-Stokes accordingly and solve it (if the memory services me right, which it, most likely, does). See White's book for instance. In your case, you must add your electrical terms to the Navier-Stokes and follow the same procedure to solve it. Look up magneto-hydrodynamics to see how to add your terms to the Navier-Stokes.

I agree that showing some work on your part would be good - perhaps you should first attempt to solve the regular problem with non-charged liquid, or for a cylindrical tank instead of a rectangular one to build intuition. Then, you can add E/B fields by utilizing Maxwell's equations in the steady state (time derivatives are 0). Further, using the structure of the tank a>>b, you can make additional assumptions on which spatial derivatives will dominate. Given the lack of cylindrical symmetry, you will likely get non-analytical results anyway, and a numerical solution to N-S eqs is your best bet
